# r how to select intercept/variable from r summary(model) based on the Pr value

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

How to return the intercept/variable/column from r summary(model) based on the Pr value?

```
cnn <- odbcConnect("CN")
dataset1 <- sqlQuery(cnn, "SELECT Year
      ,Col1 
      ,Col2
      ,Col3
      ,Col4
      ,Col5
      ,Col6
  FROM MyDB.dbo.MyTbl")

mymodel <- lm("Col1 ~ Col2 + Col3 + Col4 + Col5 + Col6", data=dataset1) 
summary(mymodel)

#> Coefficients:
#>               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|) 
#> (Intercept) -4.504e-01  1.019e+01  -0.044 0.965202 
#> Col2         1.043e-03  5.310e-04   1.963 0.064416 .  
#> Col3         6.012e-01  1.030e-01   5.836 1.27e-05 ***
#> Col4        -3.958e-03  8.751e-04  -4.523 0.000233 ***
#> Col5         5.847e-04  7.900e-02   0.007 0.994172  
#> Col6        -4.953e-05  1.667e-04  -0.297 0.769578
```

Comment: try with `broom::tidy(mymodel)`

Comment: ```res = coefficients(summary(mymodel)) ; rownames(res)[res[,4]<0.05]``` hmmm i guess you are referring to this

Comment: rownames(res)[res[,4]<0.05]
Thank you!